# How to replace a substring in C when the substring is similar to the replacement string?

Tags: c, string, substring

I've created a program in C which uses the `strstr`, `strncpy`, and `sprintf` functions to replace all substrings with a replacement string. The only flaw with my program is that when you are looking to replace for e.g. searching for "The" and wanting to replace it with "There", this causes as infinite loop, as the program keeps finding what it just replaced. How could I fix this in C, or is there another way to implement such a function in C? Thanks.

Replacement function: (its called multiple times until there are no longer any matches found).

```
char *searchAndReplace(char *text, char *search, char *replace){
  char buffer[MAX_L];
    char *ptr;
    char *modText = malloc(4096);
    if(!(ptr = strstr(text, search))){
        return;
    }
    strncpy(buffer, text, ptr-text);
    sprintf(buffer+(ptr-text), "%s%s", replace, ptr + strlen(search));
    strcpy(text, buffer);
```

Comment: Please post representative samples of your code.

Comment: Start your search for the *next* replacement at the tail of the *last* replacement text. I.e "TheQuestion" replaces "The with "There", then starts searching for the next "The" at the 'Q' in "ThereQuestion".

Comment: @WhozCraig how exactly do I get it to start from there, thats where I'm stuck I can't figure out how to pinpoint that position.

Comment: @Nassim, Are you calling your function repeatedly?

Comment: @merlin2011, yes its called repeatedly until there is no more matches.

Comment: @Nassim can you add a last check after each found result? for example there must be a space after "The " is that useful in your case?

Comment: @chouaib I would rather not add any extra characters. thanks.

Comment: The original version of the question used `static char buffer[MAX_L];` in the function. I have reservations about that. There's no obvious reason to make it static; I'm guessing you must concerned about stack overflow in some shape or form. But making the variable static means that it cannot be used concurrently (in different threads), and there's no need for that restriction. I'd simply remove the keyword static. Remember re-entrancy; don't break it unnecessarily. The question has since been updated appropriately and so have some of the answers that borrowed the `static`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ok thanks for the great advice, I will remove it. cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can return a pointer to a place in the original string **after** the previous replacement, and then call your function the next time using that pointer instead of the original pointer.

Note that you should generally use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy` everywhere in the code below, but I am trying to preserve as much of your original code as possible, so I have made simplifying assumptions.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define MAX_L 4096
char *searchAndReplace(char *text, char *search, char *replace){
    char buffer[MAX_L];
    char *ptr;
    if(!(ptr = strstr(text, search))){
        return NULL;
    }
    strncpy(buffer, text, ptr-text);
    sprintf(buffer+(ptr-text), "%s%s", replace, ptr + strlen(search));
    strcpy(text, buffer);
    return ptr + strlen(search);
}

int main(){
    char* original = malloc(MAX_L);
    memset(original, 0, MAX_L);
    strcpy(original, "The The End Is Nigh");


    char* current = original;
    do {
        current = searchAndReplace(current, "The", "There");
    } while (current);

    printf("%s\n", original);
}
```

Output:

```
There There End Is Nigh
```

Comment: nice solution! I will try and make it work for my program. Thanks mate.

Comment: Next exercise, make a version that does it in-place and guards against buffer overflow..:)

Answer (score 1):

You can look for the search string, copy up to that point to the buffer, append the replace string, advance your pointer to the point past the where you found the string. Do this in a loop until you don't find the search string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_L 1000

char *searchAndReplace(char *text, char *search, char *replace)
{
   char buffer[MAX_L];
   char *ptr;
   char *modText = NULL;

   buffer[0] ='\0';
   while ( ptr = strstr(text, search) )
   {
      strncat(buffer, text, ptr-text);
      strcat(buffer, replace);

      // If you are looking for "xx" in "xxxx",
      // There are two ways of looking at this search.
      //                                 xxxx
      // You can either look at it as    ^^
      //                                   --
      // i.e. two matches, or
      //                                 xxxx
      //                                 ^^
      //                                  --
      //                                   ++
      // i.e. three matches

      // If the first interpretation is desired...
      // text = ptr + strlen(search);

      // If the second interpretation is desired...
      text = ptr + 1;

   }
   strcat(buffer, text);

   modText = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
   strcpy(modText, buffer);
   return modText;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   char* out = searchAndReplace(argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]);
   printf("%s\n", out);

   // Free the memory allocated and returned from searchAndReplace
   free(out);
}
```

When I run

```
./test "ab cc ccd" c xyz
```

I get the following output

```
ab xyzxyz xyzxyzd
```

**Update**

Just to test what would happen if I tried WhozCraig's suggestion.

```
>> ./test "xxxxxx" xx xxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I am not sure what the OP's expectations are about this.

Comment: Running this with "xxxxxx" as the source text, "xx" as the search text, and "xxx" as the replacement text should prove... interesting. The result *should* be nine `x`. (hint: `text = ptr + 1` isn't all its cracked up to be).

Comment: @WhozCraig I just added the output of running that case.

Comment: Interesting.  Normally, you'd expect a crash, but you start mangling the search and replacement strings (which are arguments 2 and 3) as you grow argument 1, so in fact you stop.  It would be interesting to have you add: `printf("[%s] => [%s]\n", argv[2], argv[3]);` before and after the call to `searchAndReplace()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I got the expected outout, `[xx] => [xxx]` with that change. I don't know why you thought that would make any difference.

Comment: OK; my bad. I didn't notice that you've got a memory leak in your code because you allocate the space where the revised string is placed and don't release it. A more extreme variant of WhozCraig's test is `./test xxxxxxxxxxxxz x xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy` which crashes for me -- a Stack Overflow. That's not entirely fair; the same problem can be triggered with the other answer, but the buffer size is a lot bigger so it takes more effort to break it. This is how programs released to the outside world get abused. Your duty as a programmer is to ensure that the abuse doesn't break anything.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It wasn't the memory leak I was looking at (not that it isn't important); the starting-location for the next search was my point. Once found, the next source location should be searching at the discovery-point + the search-text length, not just +1, Thus xxxxxx xx xxx should result in nine x, not the sixteen being emitted by the posted code (not: i think you knew that, but not sure if RSahu did).

Comment: @WhozCraig: my mental model of operations wasn't quite right, so I misdiagnosed what was going on.  I realized what you were driving at in general terms — but was not handling all the details of the actual code correctly (hence my misdiagnosis).  The memory leak is important.  The fact that it can overflow the buffer is also important.  But my mistake was trying to do this around some work…or what passes for an attempt at work.  Now I've had time to think about it better, I see what's going on — and where I was making my mistakes.

Comment: `text = ptr + 1;` should probably be `text = ptr + strlen(search);`

Comment: @MattMcNabb exactly. Normally i do this as [one function](https://ideone.com/eIZsc7) rather than one that expects context outside for repetition, but to each their own. So long as it works.